# vim does not find and replace simple phrase that is clearly present

Tags: vim, replace, scope-resolution

I have a simple vim problem that Google hasn't managed to help me with.  Any thoughts are appreciated.

I do the following search and replace:

```
:s/numnodes/numnodes1/g
```

On a file containing the following text:

```
numprocs=0  
numnodes=0
```

I get

```
E486: Pattern not found
```

The position of the green square which indicates where I'd start typing is clearly above the pattern.  I tried searching for other short phrases not involving regex, which are also present, which also fail.  A simple /numnodes highlights matches as expected.  Does anyone have any idea what might be the matter with vim?

Answer (score 181, accepted):

Try `:%s/searchphrase/replacephase/g`

Without the `%` symbol Vim only matches and replaces on the current line.

Comment: Add 'c' next to 'g' to confirm and replace: `:%s/searchphrase/replacephase/gc`

Comment: It blows my mind how many tutorials leave out this small but important detail.

Answer (score 19):

try using this:

```
:%s/numnodes/numnodes1/g
```

Comment: Ack, the number before 's' is the line number, '%" means 'all lines' AFAIK.

Comment: its a line specification. you could also use (instead of %) .,$ to replace from current line to eof for example

Comment: as a sidenote if you select from visual mode you can then use : and it will automatically fill in the line number stuff for that region so you can replace within a region.

Comment: I've been using :s/foo/bar/g forever.  This is the first I've heard of this %.

Comment: @alternative you are a life saver, that woks like a charm and should be considered as an answer.

Comment: @Wrikken awesome, life saver comment... I didn't understand why using :s replace only one line and after replace it keep saying "Pattern not found". Now I'm understand, thanks.